# Blazor: How to show one list item at a time

Tags: razor, blazor

I am developing a blazor app which asks several questions to the user. I want to ask one question before proceeding to the next question. So, I have a list of questions, and I want to show each item from the list step-by-step instead of putting all the questions in a single view.

If I want to show all questions in a single page, then the following Index.razor will do.
This is a working a code:

```
@foreach (var item in items)
{
   <h2>@item.Question</>
}


@code
{
    List<Item> items = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        items = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>(NavigationManager.BaseUri + "items");
    }

}
```

where the `Item` class is:

```
public class Item
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; } 
}
```

BUT, I do not want that. I want to show one question at a time. Maybe something like this, i.e. where I can call some random question in a single view:

```
@* THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING *@

<h2>@items[3].Question</>


@code
{
    List<Item> items = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        items = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>(NavigationManager.BaseUri + "items");
    }

}
```

I am guessing this has something to do with the `await` stuff, but cannot figure out at all.

Anyway, If I can get this right, then I can maybe continue writing code to call each item from the list one-by-one.

p.s For the rest of the code, I am just using the default Blazor template. The `DbContext` looks like this:

```
public class QuestionsContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public QuestionsContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

}
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
[Route("items")]
[ApiController]
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    private readonly QuestionsContext _db;

    public ItemController(QuestionsContextdb)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Item>>> GetItems()
    {
        return await (_db.Items.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should describe better what is not working. However, if you want your piece of code to work, just wrap with a condition because `items` may not be populated yet: `@if(items.Count >= increment + 1){ <h2>@items[increment].Question</h2> }`.

Comment: The third code snippet is not working. I cannot get a random item from the list.  I can access each item with the @foreach loop. That works. But if I need to access a certain item from the list, that does not work. That is the third code snippet and it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to give a solution that would ideally fit your needs. For example, you haven’t really said how would you like the items to be changed — button click, timer or whatever.

Anyway, first of all, as already been mentioned you have to be sure your collection of items loaded by providing simple `if-else` statement.

Define some private fields to store data and use it for displaying.

Then, you can create a button (for sake of example) that will trigger the question update, and define a method that will be triggered.

```
@if (items is null)
{
  <p>Loading…</p
}
else 
{
  @_currentQuestion

  <button type=“button” @onclick=“UpdateCurrentQuestion”> Update Question </button>
}

@code {
  int _currentIndex = 0; // index to be incremented
  string? _currentQuestion; // displayed question

  List<Item> items = new();

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    items = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>(NavigationManager.BaseUri + "items");
    _currentQuestion = items[0].Question; // get the first question
  }

  void UpdateCurrentQuestion() 
  {
    _currentIndex++;
    _currentQuestion = items[_currentIndex].Question;      
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can’t test this right now, but it should do the trick.

Also, you can change the `UpdateCurrentQuestion` method to `async Task` and add a `Task.Delay()` if you don’t want a button.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @desmondische. That solved my problem. Sorry for not showing the entire problem. I was trying to abide SO rules by asking just one question at a time and I had to strip my actual code to show just the problem. Now, I can proceed with the next steps and I will definitely upload more questions as I proceed.

Comment: @moostang I am glad that it helped you! I will be happy to help you next time :)

Comment: Here is another question from me.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/75116243/4387406?sem=2 Many thanks.

Comment: Intersting! Gonna take a look